# group_modify does not behave as expected when the function is psych::alpha()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to run `psych::alpha` on a grouped dataset  `group_map` works but [as expected](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html) the list doesn't state the groups, it indexes the countries ([[1]] etc) which is **not** useful to me, so it is not a viable alternative.
The reference website examples imply there is no argument additions between `group_map` and `group_modify` but passing through `group_modify` gives me the error:

```
Number of categories should be increased  in order to count frequencies. 
Error: The result of .f should be a data frame.
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 3. dplyr:::group_modify.grouped_df(., ~psych::alpha(.x, check.keys = TRUE))
 5. dplyr:::group_map.data.frame(.data, fun, .keep = .keep)
 6. dplyr:::map2(chunks, group_keys, .f, ...)
 7. base::mapply(.f, .x, .y, MoreArgs = list(...), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
>
```

This happens in both my dataset where I:

```
df%>% select(groupVar, vars1:var4)%>% group_by(groupVar)%>% 
group_modify(~ psych::alpha(.x, check.keys = TRUE))
```

as well as with the example code adapted from the tidyverse website which substitutes `head()` for `psych::alpha`:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_modify(~ psych::alpha(.x, check.keys = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `group_modify` expects a `data.frame` as output.  According to `?group_modify`

> group_modify() is good for "data frame in, data frame out".

We could use `group_map` as the output of `alpha` is a `list`

> group_map() returns a list of results from calling .f on each group.

```
library(dplyr)
out <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_map(~ psych::alpha(.x, check.keys = TRUE))
```

check the output of elements of the `list` output from `group_map`

```
str(out[[1]])
List of 14
 $ total        :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  9 variables:
  ..$ raw_alpha: num 0.663
  ..$ std.alpha: num 0.672
  ..$ G6(smc)  : num 0.68
  ..$ average_r: num 0.338
  ..$ S/N      : num 2.05
  ..$ ase      : num 0.0535
  ..$ mean     : num 2.54
  ..$ sd       : num 0.196
  ..$ median_r : num 0.273
 $ alpha.drop   :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ raw_alpha: num [1:4] 0.34 0.425 0.69 0.691
  ..$ std.alpha: num [1:4] 0.496 0.553 0.683 0.663
  ..$ G6(smc)  : num [1:4] 0.404 0.454 0.672 0.664
  ..$ average_r: num [1:4] 0.247 0.292 0.418 0.396
  ..$ S/N      : num [1:4] 0.986 1.239 2.153 1.965
  ..$ alpha se : num [1:4] 0.1243 0.1086 0.0426 0.0562
  ..$ var.r    : num [1:4] 0.00608 0.00119 0.07961 0.09217
  ..$ med.r    : num [1:4] 0.233 0.278 0.278 0.267
 $ item.stats   :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ n     : num [1:4] 50 50 50 50
  ..$ raw.r : num [1:4] 0.905 0.888 0.472 0.445
  ..$ std.r : num [1:4] 0.806 0.758 0.626 0.649
  ..$ r.cor : num [1:4] 0.796 0.729 0.393 0.424
  ..$ r.drop: num [1:4] 0.73 0.66 0.273 0.328
  ..$ mean  : num [1:4] 5.006 3.428 1.462 0.246
  ..$ sd    : num [1:4] 0.352 0.379 0.174 0.105
 $ response.freq: NULL
 $ keys         : Named num [1:4] 1 1 1 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
 $ scores       : num [1:50] 2.55 2.38 2.35 2.35 2.55 ...
 $ nvar         : int 4
 $ boot.ci      : NULL
 $ boot         : NULL
 $ Unidim       :List of 1
  ..$ Unidim: num 0.625
 $ var.r        : num 0.0418
 $ Fit          :List of 1
  ..$ Fit.off: num 0.926
 $ call         : language psych::alpha(x = .x, check.keys = TRUE)
 $ title        : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "psych" "alpha"
```

#### Update

There is a `summary` method for `alpha` which can return a `data.frame`

```
out <- iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   group_modify(~ psych::alpha(.x, check.keys = TRUE) %>%
                  summary)
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 3 x 10
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    raw_alpha std.alpha `G6(smc)` average_r `S/N`    ase  mean    sd median_r
  <fct>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 setosa         0.663     0.672     0.680     0.338  2.05 0.0535  2.54 0.196    0.273
2 versicolor     0.833     0.877     0.877     0.640  7.10 0.0308  3.57 0.323    0.612
3 virginica      0.774     0.785     0.818     0.477  3.65 0.0418  4.28 0.364    0.429
```

Comment: The reason `group_map` is not useful is *because* it produces a list, so the groups are unnamed and thus not useful for graphing (see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4531). I tried making it a dataframe first but couldn't get it to work, but also my original data IS a dataframe so still unclear why it wouldn't work.